# Newtonsoft JSON : Error getting value from 'NativeCalendarName' on 'System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo'

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, deserialization

I'm trying to serialize dataset to JSON in my Xamarin application using NewtonSoftJSON but stuck to below error

> Error getting value from 'NativeCalendarName'
>   on'System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo'.

Though i'm not using any datetime in my dataset I'm facing the error. Please help me out to resolve the same. Thanks
So far I have done

```
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dsComp, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, 
    new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings() 
    { 
        ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore   
    });

using(var streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename, true)) 
{
    streamWriter.WriteLine(output);
}
```

Comment: It's trying to serialize the DateTime, its properties, all of its properties' properties, and on and on.  Quick solution is to convert the property into a string containing the UTC value of the DateTime, and add a method on the dataset, if possible, to convert it back to a DateTime.

Comment: Might want to add your json too.

Comment: But @Will My dataset does not contain any datetime nor any datetime format. Is there any property that will skip this date format check?

Comment: Maybe not directly, but someone down the line has a public reference to it.  You just got an answer that is better, btw.

Comment: Ya @Will , trying the same. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

You have to tell how to serialize Datetime format. Try this

```
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dsComp, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, 
    new JsonSerializerSettings() 
    { 
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore, 
        DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @Musfiqur, but still its giving me the same error. Code throws out near Formatting, its not entering the setting code. Pls help

Comment: Can you provide the class structure of dsComp object?

Comment: dsComp is a dataset, and it contains table with column 'State' & 'City'

Comment: Try this llnk: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2008/Sep/03/DataTable-JSON-Serialization-in-JSONNET-and-JavaScriptSerializer

Comment: var dataSet = new DataSet("dataSet");
var table = new DataTable();
var stateColumn = new DataColumn("State");
var cityColumn = new DataColumn("City");
table.Columns.Add(stateColumn);
table.Columns.Add(cityColumn);
dataSet.Tables.Add(table);
for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
            {
                DataRow newRow = table.NewRow();
                newRow["State"] = "State " + i;
                table.Rows.Add(newRow);
            }
dataSet.AcceptChanges();
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataSet, Formatting.Indented);

Comment: What is your version of newtonsoft?